# how to control animation speed jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have two functions, one is animate the control **animate_as()** another one is get the animation value from database using ajax **get_speed()**.

in **get_speed()** function i get the value from database and store it in a hidden input tag **txtspeedvalue**, and use this hidden tag in **animate_as()** function

if i run the code its run smoothly. when i change the speed in database its not reflect in animation .

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   var winwith=$("#animate").width();

    var str1="+=";
    var str2=winwith-42; // image with 42
    var str3="px";
     var res = str1.concat(str2, str3);
    get_speed();
    var x = parseInt($("#txtspeedvalue").val());
    animate_as(x);

    function animate_as(speed_as) {
    $("#animate").animate({
            backgroundPositionX: res,
            backgroundPositionY: "+=0px"
        },speed_as);

        $("#animate").animate({
            backgroundPositionX: "0px",
            backgroundPositionY: "0px"
        },speed_as);

        speed_as= parseInt($("#txtspeedvalue").val());
        animate_as(speed_as);
    }

function get_speed(){

    var uid = localStorage.getItem('userid');
    var getvalue = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/get_user_info.php",
        data: {uid:uid},
        async: false
    }).success(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){get_speed();}, 5000);
    }).responseText;

    document.getElementById("divspeed").innerHTML = getvalue;

   // $("#txtspeed").val(getvalue);
    $("#txtspeedvalue").val(getvalue);
}



function setuserid(uid) {
    localStorage.setItem('userid', uid);
}

});
```

Comment: sorry.. not get..